# Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type ArrayList<Integer>[], even though the get method is applicable to ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a method that takes an ArrayList and uses the element at a certain index in a different location , yet when I use the .get(int) method in the code, I get an error.

```
static void linreg(ArrayList<Integer> x[], ArrayList<Integer> y[]) {

        double sum_x = 0, sum_y = 0, int n = 15;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

          sum_x += x.get(i); - Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type ArrayList<Integer>[]
          sum_y += y.get(i); - Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type ArrayList<Integer>[]
```

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Delete both `[]`.  They don't do what you think they do.

Comment: Side note: it is usually much better to do a `List<List<Integer>>` construct than to mix arrays with lists as you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters `x` and `y` are arrays. Arrays in java don't have a `get` method. That's why you get the error. You don't even need them as arrays. You just need them as lists which do have `get` method.

```
static void linreg(List<Integer> x, List<Integer> y) {

        double sum_x = 0, sum_y = 0, int n = 15;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

          sum_x += x.get(i); 
          sum_y += y.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(sum_x);
        System.out.println(sum_y);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`x` is not of type `ArrayList<Integer>`, it is of type `ArrayList<Integer>[]`. (Note that it is not recommended to use this syntax exactly because of the confusion you had.) Perhaps you didn't mean to have both an array and a list.